# Drawing a large grid with ellipsis in between rows and columns

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a novice with TikZ, trying to draw a large grid. Want to emphasize that it's a large grid by replacing a row/column with ellipsis (ldots/vdots); like how you would do in a large matrix. Haven't gone very far yet; any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `nicematrix` package can help?

Comment: Realised that having a matrix would be easier later on but ended up finding something that worked for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I offer you two alternatives. The idea is the same in both of them: to reduce the code with the help of the `\foreach` command.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line join=cap]
% BLACK GRID
\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{%
  \begin{scope}[rotate=\i,transform shape]
    \draw[step=0.5cm] (0.5,0.5) grid (3,3);
    \foreach\j in {0.75,1.25,...,2.75}
      \node at (0,\j) {$\cdots$};
  \end{scope}
}
\node at (0,0.1) {$\ddots$}; % vertical align "by hand"
% BLUE GRID
\begin{scope}[shift={(7,0)},blue]
\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{%
  \begin{scope}[rotate=\i]
    \draw[step=0.5cm] (0.4,0.4) grid (3,3);
    \foreach\j in {0.5,1,...,3}
      \draw[dotted] (-0.3,\j) -- (0.3,\j);
  \end{scope}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out myself so here goes

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=.5cm-\pgflinewidth, outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (0,0) grid (2.5,2.5);
    \node at (3,1.75) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,1.25) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,0.75) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,0.25) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,2.25) {\ldots};
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (3.4999,0) grid (6,2.5);
    \node at (0.25,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (0.75,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (1.25,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (1.75,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (2.25,3) {\vdots};
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (0,3.499) grid (2.5,6);
    \node at (3.75,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (4.75,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (4.25,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (5.25,3) {\vdots};
    \node at (5.75,3) {\vdots};
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (3.499,3.499) grid (6,6);
    \node at (3,3.75) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,4.25) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,4.75) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,5.25) {\ldots};
    \node at (3,5.75) {\ldots};
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This not seems to be an answer, rather should be part of your question.

Comment: But this is pretty much what I wanted, just that it took me an hour to figure it out. Should I instead just delete the question now that I'm not looking for an answer anymore?

Comment: Don't delete it. It's a self-answered question, and that's fine. But I suggest that you complete your code, so that it can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks @Roland for fixing that